# Reduce processing time for 'While read' loop

Tags: arrays, shell, awk, while-loop

New to shell scripting..

I have a huge csv file, with a varying length f11, like

"000000aaad000000bhb200000uwwed..."
"000000aba200000bbrb2000000wwqr00000caba2000000bhbd000000qwew..."
.
.

**After splitting the string in size of 10, I need 6-9 characters. then I have to join them back using delimiter '|'** like

0aaa|0bhb|uwwe...
0aba|bbrb|0wwq|caba|0bhb|0qwe...

and join the processed f11 with other fields

this is the time taken for processing 10k records ->

real    4m43.506s
user    0m12.366s
sys     0m12.131s

20K records ->
real    5m20.244s
user    2m21.591s
sys     3m20.042s

80K records (around 3.7Million f11 split and merge with '|') ->

real    21m18.854s
user    9m41.944s
sys     13m29.019s

My expected time is 30mins for processing 650K records (around 56Million f11 split and merge). Any way to optimize ?

```
while read -r line1; do
    f10=$( echo $line1 | cut -d',' -f1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10)
    echo $f10 >> $path/other_fields
    
    f11=$( echo $line1 | cut -d',' -f11 )
    f11_trim=$(echo "$f11" | tr -d '"')
    echo $f11_trim | fold -w10 > $path/f11_extract 

    cat $path/f11_extract | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c6-9 >> $path/str_list_trim
    
    arr=($(cat $path/str_list_trim))
    printf "%s|" ${arr[@]} >> $path/str_list_serialized
    printf '\n' >> $path/str_list_serialized
    arr=()
    
    rm $path/f11_extract
    rm $path/str_list_trim

done < $input
sed -i 's/.$//' $path/str_list_serialized
sed -i 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g' $path/str_list_serialized

paste -d "," $path/other_fields $path/str_list_serialized > $path/final_out
```

Comment: I suggest to use only `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Are the quotation marks part of the file? Your shown example contains no `,`. Please add sample input with field separator (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output with field separator for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: "xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"00000aaaaD00000bbbbD00000abcdD00000dwasD00000dedsD00000ddfgD00000dsdfD00000snfjD00000djffD00000wedfD00000asdfZ"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"00000aaaaD00000bbbbD00000abcdD00000dwasD00000deds"

Comment: Please no comment.

Comment: @Cyrus while read has uniform speed for all file sizes, tried using only sed/awk.. processing time increases as file size increases

Comment: "xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"aaaa|bbbb|abcd|dwas|deds|ddfg|dsdf|snfj|djff|wedf|asdf"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"aaaa|bbbb|abcd|dwas|deds"

Comment: What about dropping the `echo` and `cat`? Instead of `echo <file> | cut ...` you can do `cut ... <file>`, ... (instead of `cat <file> | awk ...`, you can do `awk ... <file>`).

Comment: @GD, Thanks for showing your efforts. Please do mention your sample of input and expected output more clearly in your question. Also mention Logic of getting your expected output in your question; to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not time-efficient due to:

- invoking multiple commands including awk within the loop.
- generating many intermediate temporal files.

You can do the job just with awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '                                    # assign input/output field separator to a comma
{
    len = length($11)                                   # length of the 11th field
    s = ""; d = ""                                      # clear output string and the delimiter
    for (i = 1; i <= len / 10; i++) {                   # iterate over the 11th field
        s = s d substr($11, (i - 1) * 10 + 6, 4)        # concatenate 6-9th substring of 10 characters long chunks
        d = "|"                                         # set the delimiter to a pipe character
    }
    $11 = "\"" s "\""                                   # assign the 11th field to the generated string
} 1' "$input"                                           # the final "1" tells awk to print all fields
```

Example of the input:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,000000aaad000000bhb200000uwwed
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,000000aba200000bbrb2000000wwqr00000caba2000000bhbd000000qwew
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"0aaa|0bhb|uwwe"
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"0aba|bbrb|0wwq|caba|0bhb|0qwe"
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks.

Significant improvement. it just takes 5seconds to process 80k records. Earlier it was 21mins.

real    0m5.485s
user    0m4.971s
sys     0m0.080s

Comment: Just a clarification, are characters 's' and 'd' keywords for awk ?

Comment: No, they are just the variable names; intended to mean `s` for string, `d` for delimiter.