# Awk command to split nth field text and insert as new rows

Tags: bash, shell, awk, while-loop

This is a continuation to my previous question below, just checking whether I will be able to process this model in the same time

[Reduce processing time for 'While read' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717681/reduce-processing-time-for-while-read-loop)

I have a huge csv file, with a varying length field 11, like

```
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"00000aaaaD00000bbbbD00000abcdD00000dwasD00000dedsD00000ddfgD00000dsdfD00000snfjD00000djffD00000wedfD00000asdfZ"  
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"00000aaaaD00000bbbbD00000abcdD00000dwasD00000dedsD"
```

After splitting the field 11 in size of 10, I need 6-9 characters. then I have to insert it as new rows
I need the output as below,

```
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"aaaa"  
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"bbbb"  
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"abcd"
.  
.  
.  
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"asdf"  
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"djff"  
.  
.  
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"deds"
```

```
while read -r line1; do
    icount=$[icount+1]
    col_11=$( echo $line1 | cut -d',' -f11 )
    col_10=$( echo $line1 | cut -d',' -f1,2,3,4,5,7,10)
    #echo $col_11
    col_11_trim=$(echo "$col_11" | tr -d '"')
    #echo $col_11_trim
    echo $col_11_trim | fold -w10 > $path/col_11_extract 
    while read -r line2; do
        ocount=$[ocount+1]
        strng_cut=$(echo $line2 | cut -c6-9) 
                echo "$col_10",\""$strng_cut"\"  >> $path/final_out     
    done < $path/col_11_extract 
done < $input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     {
       eleven=$11;
       len=length(eleven);
       for(i=2; i<len-1; i=i+10){
         $11="\"" substr(eleven, i+5, 4) "\"";
         print;
       }
     }' file
```

`for` loop starts at position `2` and ends with `len-1` because of quotes in field 11.

Output:

```
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"aaaa"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"bbbb"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"abcd"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"dwas"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"deds"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"ddfg"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"dsdf"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"snfj"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"djff"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"wedf"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,11,"asdf"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"aaaa"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"bbbb"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"abcd"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"dwas"
"xx","x",x,x,x,xx,xx,"x",x,5,"deds"
```

Comment: Cool, worked. Reduced processing time from 9s to 0.025s for 10 input records (1400 output records).

Comment: Can you explain i+5 in substring and how strings were added as new rows ?

Comment: `i+5` skips the first 5 characters that are not needed in every substring. `print` outputs row with new 11th field.